# Matlab: How do I compare two string arrays and then select out the number values associated with those strings?

Tags: string, matlab, compare

I have one array of strings that I want to use to pull out samples from a larger matrix of data that I have. Right now I have the one array of strings, `1200x1`. And my actual data 'names' (string array that denotes what the values correspond to `6855x1`, and 'data' is `6855x2`.

This is what I came up with:

```
C = intersect(names,sites) %To find common strings
```

%To find where these strings are in my original dataset:

```
Q=zeros(length(C),1)
for i=1:length(C)
    for j=1
   while strcmp(C(i),names(j))==0
       j=j+1
       Q(i)=j
   end 
    end
end
```

%To then use the above values to compile a new vector with the actual data values from 'data':

```
A=zeros(length(Q),1)
for i=1:length(Q)
A(i) = mock(Q(i),1)
```

The only problem is I am running the second set of loops I listed right now, and it is obvious that it will take several hours. I think there must be a quicker way without setting up three loops. Does anyone know a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your loop over Q can be trivially accelerated, as:

```
A = mock(Q,1);
```

although I suspect that you meant data(Q,2).

If you store your name list in a cell array rather than a regular array, you should be able to accelerate things further. Assume that data is a cell array, names{1:6855} and value list numbers(1:6855).

```
A = zeros(length(C),1);
for i1=1:length(C)
    A(i1)=numbers(strcmp(C(i1),names));
end
```

Comment: Thanks. So do you mean that by listing just A(i1)=numbers(strcmp(C(i1),data)); matlab will compare the strings in my 'C' array to the strings in the new 'data' array that is to contain both strings and numbers and then when it finds a match it will output the numbers into A? So I can simplify everything I had to just that?

Comment: Oh, there was a minor typo - I said "data" when I meant "names". It'll be fixed in a moment. strcmp can compare a string with a cell array of strings, and the output is a logical array indicating which entries match. So long as the entries of "names" (which should be the string part of "data") are unique, you'll get a single result from numbers(strcmp) for each entry in C. I'm not sure how it'll interact with "intersect", though.

Comment: @GlenO Instead of the loop, I believe that you can also employ the second output argument of `ismember(C, names)`. Maybe that can speed up things even more.

Comment: Maybe. I don't have experience with ismember beyond testing existing code here on stackoverflow. Perhaps you could create an appropriate solution. As I use Octave, I can't do speed comparisons for Matlab, anyway, so I can't test to see which method is faster.

Comment: @GlenO `ismember` is also availabe in Octave.

Comment: Yes, but Octave and Matlab are different with regards to speed. A speed test in Octave is meaningless to Matlab.